# How to use parameters in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a project where there are some functions with parameters. Here is the code

```
sortNumbers(a,b,order){
   if (order === 'desc') {
      return Number(b.newScore) - Number(a.newScore);
    } else {
      return Number(a.newScore) - Number(b.newScore);
    }
}
```

Then the function is used in a react component called "TableHeaderColumn" without using parameters. And it works:

```
<TableHeaderColumn className="" dataField="newScore" dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortNumbers}>
     Title
</TableHeaderColumn>
```

The function is called without using parameters. My question is, let say I want to add a new parameter to the function, how do I call the function?
This does not work:

```
sortNumbers(a,b,order,newParam){
   if (order === 'desc') {
      return Number(b.newParam) - Number(a.newParam);
    } else {
      return Number(a.newParam) - Number(b.newParam);
    }
}
<BootstrapTable data={this.props.resData}>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField="oldScore" dataSort={true} sortFunct={this.sortNumbers(oldScore)}>       
         Old Score
    </TableHeaderColumn>
   <TableHeaderColumn dataField="newScore" dataSort={true} sortFunct={this.sortNumbers(newScore)}>
         New Score
   </TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

Comment: Presumably `TableHeaderColumn`'s `sortFunc` prop is, as the name suggests, expecting a function that the component can then *call for you* to sort the rows. It's not really clear what you're expecting `newParam` to even do, but maybe look into partial application and higher order functions.

Comment: can you show the TableHeaderColumn component code

Comment: It looks like you definitely want a higher-order function. You want to call `this.sortNumbers('newScore')` and *return a function* that sorts two objects based on `a['newScore']` and `b['newScore']`.